# hiding the running program window

Tags: batch-file

1. I have .mp3 converted as .exe to
   make it as self playing its done.
2. But a window is appearing while
   music is playing.
3. I want to hide
   that window while music is
   playing [only using .bat file code]
4. So please help me for the .bat
   file code

Answer (score 1):

There is no way to hide a window in pure batch, your best alternative is to relaunch yourself (the .bat) with the START command and the /MIN switch, this would run it minimized and not hidden (You would use a special parameter and check %1 to see if you need to relaunch or not)

Comment: +1, It seems to be correct for pure batch, but it's possible with a batch/wsh hybrid (like zerg and protoss hybrids :-) )

Comment: If someone wants to go the batch/WSH hybrid route: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2591310/is-there-a-short-cut-for-desktop-folder-in-windows-batch/2592639#2592639