# There's any way to run vbscript directly to wscript or cscript command line

Tags: command-line, batch-file, vbscript, wsh

I want to run a vbs command from command line as I would in batch calling

```
cmd.exe /c "echo.Hello World! & pause"
```

Obviously this doesn't work

```
wscript /C MsgBox("Hello world")
```

I could print the vbs and then call the temporary file and then delete it

```
cmd.exe /c "echo. [VBSCODE] > temp.vbs & wscript temp.vbs & del temp.vbs"
```

but this is too messy, and I don't want the prompt poping up.

Answer (score 20):

This works directly on the command line:

```
mshta vbscript:Execute("MsgBox(""Message"",64,""Title"")(window.close)")
```

also for several commands:

```
mshta vbscript:Execute("MsgBox ""Message"",64,""Title"":MsgBox ""Hello again!"",64,""Hello"":close")
```

Comment: Yes it sure does!  At least on Win7 x64.

Comment: is there a way with w/csript ?

Answer (score 2):

VBScript requires a file for its source code. You want to specify stdin as the "file", but there is no mechanism to do that. So the answer is no - you cannot generate and run VBS code from the command line without using a temporary file.

Most people use a batch script to write temp VBS code, execute, and then delete the temp code,  as PA has demonstrated.

I have discovered a mechanism to embed the VBS code within the batch file, without the need for a temporary file. But it is not very pretty. See [Is it possible to embed and execute VBScript within a batch file without using a temporary file?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/9074476/1012053)

It is much cleaner to [embed JScript within a batch file](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5656250/1012053).

Answer (score 0):

avoid typing over and over the same, just create a bat with the commands to run

**sovb.bat**

```
@echo off
echo %* >%temp%\temp.vbs
wscript %temp%\temp.vbs
del %temp%\temp.vbs
```

and then from the command line, invoke it

```
sovb MsgBox("Hello World")
```