# Running inline vbscript code from java

Tags: java, vbscript

I'd like to execute vbscript code from java

I understand that the following code executes a vbs file.

```
Runtime.getRuntime().exec("wscript test.vbs");
```

But what I need is to execute the code inside vbs file itself from java instead of having the vbs file saved in the system. In my environment I am not allowed to save vbs files in system.

I am looking for something like

```
Runtime.getRuntime().exec("wscript 'vbscript code itself'");
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [There's any way to run vbscript directly to wscript or cscript command line](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13115508/theres-any-way-to-run-vbscript-directly-to-wscript-or-cscript-command-line)

Comment: @JacobKrall , In my case I am not allowed to use a batch or vbs file in the system. I am looking for a solution to execute the actual vbscript code itself.

Answer (score 3):

You can't. The VBScript hosts (wscript, cscript, ie, mshta) all work with input files. There is a (dated) [script control](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa227633%28v=vs.60%29.aspx) that eats code, but to use that from Java, you'll have to do COM.

In your shoes I'd forget VBScript and research "scripting Java" [random link](http://java-source.net/open-source/scripting-languages).

Answer (score 0):

This runs from the command line,

```
mshta vbscript:Execute("Dim sapi:Set sapi=CreateObject(""sapi.spvoice""):sapi.Speak ""THIS IS A TEST OF THE EMERGENCY BROADCAST SYSTEM."":set sapi=nothing ")
```