# How to send "Enter-key" through batch file to server connected via batch file

Tags: batch-file, server, remote-desktop

**Hi guys**

**With Gerhard's help, these below codes work perfectly for me**

```
@echo off

set "range=10.151.12.11  10.151.13.11  10.151.27.11"
for %%i in (%range%) do (
   start "" cmdkey.exe /generic:"%%i" /user:"buffer" /pass:"123$"
   start "" mstsc.exe /admin /w:1600 /v:"%%i"

   timeout /t 1
)
```

**In the below code, I made some changes to send the enter key, but it does not work**

@echo off

```
set "range=10.151.12.11  10.151.13.11  10.151.27.11"
for %%i in (%range%) do

 (
   start "" cmdkey.exe /generic:"%%i" /user:"buffer" /pass:"123$"
   start "" mstsc.exe /admin /w:1600 /v:"%%i"

 WScript.CreateObject("WScript.Shell").SendKeys("{Enter}");

   timeout /t 1
)
```

**Does anyone know how to send "Enter-key" in between these loops?**

**I want to send "Enter-key" after server is connected, then second server will connect**

Answer (score 1):

The simplest way to assemble an *hybrid* Batch file is combining it with JScript code, as in [this example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15167742/execute-wshshell-command-from-a-batch-script/15176096#15176096):

```
@if (@CodeSection == @Batch) @then


@echo off

set "range=10.151.12.11  10.151.13.11  10.151.27.11"
for %%i in (%range%) do (
   start "" cmdkey.exe /generic:"%%i" /user:"buffer" /pass:"123$"
   start "" mstsc.exe /admin /w:1600 /v:"%%i"

   Cscript //nologo //E:JScript "%~F0"

   timeout /t 1
)
goto :EOF


@end


WScript.CreateObject("WScript.Shell").SendKeys("{Enter}");
```

However, in order for this trick to work, the *receiving window* must have keyboard focus when the key is "pressed". Perhaps you need to also use [AppActivate method](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/windows/internet-explorer/ie-developer/windows-scripting/wzcddbek(v=vs.84)) to do that...

Answer (score -1):

You are very close, but your problem is that `WScript.CreateObject` is not a batch command, but rather a VBScript command. In order to run that command in a batch script, you need to invoke the `cscript` interpreter for that line. Unfortunately, `cscript` only accepts files so you have to create a file with the `WScript` command in it.

```
set "range=10.151.12.11  10.151.13.11  10.151.27.11"
for %%i in (%range%) do (
    start "" cmdkey.exe /generic:"%%i" /user:"buffer" /pass:"123$"
    start "" mstsc.exe /admin /w:1600 /v:"%%i"
    
    >hit_enter.vbs echo WScript.CreateObject("WScript.Shell"^).SendKeys("{Enter}"^)
    cscript /nologo hit_enter.vbs
    del hit_enter.vbs
    timeout /t 1
)
```

Comment: Connecting to the server was successful, but sending the "enter-key" didn't work

Comment: How do you know it didn't work? What error message did you get?

Comment: The connection to the server has an OK button; when we click on it, we will open the server fully so that we know your code won't be sent to the server and click on OK.

Comment: You're not going to be able to run local code on a remote host.