# path of user desktop in batch files

Tags: batch-file, windows-7

I am doing a simple batch file to copy folders and files located under the same path of the batch files to the desktop. I can easily get the path where the batch file is located using

```
%~dp0
```

but I want to know how to get the path of the user's desktop (I am using Widows 7 Ultimate)

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think this one should be ok too

```
%systemdrive%\Documents and Settings\All Users\Desktop
```

Regards

Comment: @Jack_111 - This works on XP, but does not work on Win 7. You really should accept the Mali answer, as it is more general. Your solution is also good, but not everyone has access to the registry (I don't at my workplace)

Comment: This actually **does** work in Windows 7.  For backwards compatibility, "Documents and Settings" and associated directories are mirrored so older installers will work correctly.  (tested on windows 7 x64)

Comment: @Jack_111 the problem with this solution is that it puts the files on the desktop accessible for all users. So everyone using the computer can access them, not only the user running the script. Where as Malis answer does exactly what you asked: give you the location of the current user's desktop.

Answer (score 85):

I suppose you're under windows environnement, so `%USERPROFILE%\Desktop` should be ok

Comment: The first Answer I have posted I think it is more general and it gives the desktop path in any case (The desktop is not in the user profile) and your answer as well works and I have posted that after in the normal and usual case that the desktop in the user profile (I have never seen a desktop not in the user profile)

Comment: Doesn't work on my work laptop (Windows 7). kgimpel's solution outputs the right one (`D:\Users\%USERNAME%\Desktop`). Sounds like `%USERPROFILE%` can be inacurrate on some contexts.

Comment: This is NOT valid solution for localized Windows, eg. in Polish version "Desktop" will be "Pulpit" and Desktop path will be "%USERPROFILE%\Pulpit".

Answer (score 25):

If **Desktop** locations in a **different folder** only this will be correct answer:

Batch string:

```
for /f "usebackq tokens=3*" %%D IN (`reg query "HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Explorer\User Shell Folders" /v Desktop`) do set DESKTOP=%%D
```

V2 (Works with spaces) 4.10.2016:

```
for /f "usebackq tokens=1,2,*" %%B IN (`reg query "HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Explorer\User Shell Folders" /v Desktop`) do set DESKTOP=%%D
```

If you have non-ASCII symbols, you also need to convert ANSI encoding to OEM, example for cyrillic:

```
CHCP 1251 >Nul
for /f "usebackq tokens=1,2,*" %%B IN (`reg query "HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Explorer\User Shell Folders" /v Desktop`) do set DESKTOP=%%D
CHCP 866 >Nul
for /f "delims=" %%i IN ('echo %DESKTOP%') do set DESKTOP=%%i
```

Then just use:

```
echo %DESKTOP%
```

Comment: Great, thanks for the fix, +1 to you. I've also added to your answer a little info and code for encoding handling, hope you don't mind.

Comment: All of these result in a similar error: `%%D was unexpected at this time`

Comment: Just to point 3 things out. (to improve the code and help anyone's understanding) 1). We don't need to use `usebackq`, we can use single quotes around the command instead. 2). We only need `tokens=2*` since we just want everything after the 2nd token. 3). The alphabet are like indices for our selected tokens, so might as well use `%%a` to represent our first token. Then `%%b` represents our * token, which is the entire Data field. (Also if the Name had a space like "My Videos", the Type would be the 3rd token, so we'd use `tokens=3*` if Name has 1 space)

Answer (score 24):

This is the location of the current users desktop:

```
%userprofile%\desktop
```

Comment: Does not work if the desktop has been remapped somewhere else.

Answer (score 3):

I found the answer

```
Regedit /e /a dd.txt       

"HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Explorer\Shell Folders"

find /i  dd.txt  "Desktop" >d.txt
For /F  "tokens=2 delims==" %%a in (d.txt) do set mydesktop=%%a
```

Comment: or simpler one 

    %userprofile%\desktop 

if the desktop is in the user profile and that's the common and normal case

Comment: That answer was already given by Mali. Don't try to be the hero here ;-)

Answer (score 2):

Cleanest solution just for Desktop:

```
for /f "tokens=2*" %%a in ('reg query "HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Explorer\User Shell Folders" /v Desktop') do set DESKTOP=%%b

echo %DESKTOP%
```

tokens=Type (2), then remaining Data (*) so location whitespace isn't tokenized. (spaces are allowed)

---

But if you're looking for any registry value which may not exist:

```
@echo off

set SUBKEY=HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Explorer\User Shell Folders
set VALUE_NAME=Desktop

for /f "tokens=*" %%a in ('reg query "%SUBKEY%" /v "%VALUE_NAME%" 2^>nul') do set LINE=%%a

if defined LINE goto else
    echo "%VALUE_NAME%" value not found.
    goto end
:else
    for /f "tokens=2,3 delims=#" %%a in ("%LINE:    =#%") do (
        echo Key: %SUBKEY%
        echo Name: %VALUE_NAME%
        echo Type: %%a
        echo Data: %%b
    )
:end

echo[
pause
```

`tokens=*` gets the whole line (Name + Type + Data) which are separated by 4 spaces

`%LINE:    =#%` replaces the 4 spaces with hashtags so we can deliminate the tokens properly

`tokens=2,3` gets us the Type and Data fields which get put into `%%a` and `%%b`

If you just want the Data you can do `tokens=3` and it'll be in `%%a`. (since it's the only token)

Of all the examples i've been looking at all over the web, i haven't seen anyone else collecting the whole line and swapping the 4 spaces so they can tokenize properly. They all let it split at every whitespace, which can exist at both the Name and the Data fields. Of course if you're just after a specific value however (like "Desktop") you know the Type will be the 2nd token, and the remaining Data (*) is the last token. If you wanted a one liner for "My Pictures", you'd do `token=3*` instead. ("My" "Pictures" "Type" (3) "Data" (*))

Also the `2^>nul` simply prevents the reg query command telling us if the value doesn't exist.

Answer (score 1):

The **default** for the Windows desktop directory of current user is defined with `%USERPROFILE%\Desktop`. `USERPROFILE` is one of the predefined [Windows environment variables](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Environment_variable#Windows).

So it would be possible to use just the following folder path:

```
"%UserProfile%\Desktop"
```

But it would be better to get the desktop directory path from Windows registry instead of using simply the default. There are two registry keys containing a string value with name `Desktop` with the path to user's desktop directory:

- `HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Explorer\User Shell Folders`
  This registry key contains several string values usually of type `REG_EXPAND_SZ` which define the paths to the various shell folders defined for the current user account. The shell folders contain usually an environment variable reference like `%USERPROFILE%` which is the reason for the type `REG_EXPAND_SZ` which means the string value must be additionally expanded to get absolute path to the shell folder. The batch file below expands the environment variable reference by using the command **CALL** to force one more command line parsing by Windows command processor.
  For example, the command `set "DesktopFolder=%%~K"` becomes first on execution of `for` the command `set "DesktopFolder=%USERPROFILE%\Desktop"`. This command is parsed a second time by `cmd.exe` to something like `set "DesktopFolder=C:\Users\UserName\Desktop"` because of the command `call` before really executing the command `set` to define the environment variable `DesktopFolder` with the real absolute folder name read from the Windows registry.
- `HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Explorer\Shell Folders`
  This registry key contains nearly the same string values as the registry key above, but the string values are usually of type `REG_SZ`. This registry key is for downwards compatibility for applications not supporting the other registry key with the string values with environment variable references.

It is possible that a shell folder is defined only in one of the two registry keys. For example on Windows XP the string values `Administrative Tools`, `CD Burning`, `Fonts` and `Recent` exist only under registry key `Shell Folders` and do not exist under key `User Shell Folders`.

Information added by [Compo](https://stackoverflow.com/users/6738015/compo) with comments below my similar answer on:
[How to create a directory in the user's desktop directory?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/58516212/3074564)

1. Windows itself uses by default the string values defined under key `User Shell Folders` and uses a string value defined under key `Shell Folders` only if not existing under key `User Shell Folders`.
2. Windows does not propagate a modification on a string value under key `User Shell Folders` to the string value with same name under key `Shell Folders` if a user or a program modifies directly in registry a string value under key `User Shell Folders` without making appropriate change to key with same name under key `Shell Folders`.
   So in case of `Desktop` in `User Shell Folders` contains a different directory path than `Desktop` in `Shell Folders`, Windows uses the path defined with `Desktop` in `User Shell Folders`.

A user has the freedom to change any folder to whatever the user wants. But the user must take care to change a string value in both registry keys on existing twice. Some of the shell folders can be easily modified via an option on graphical user interface of Windows or a Windows application like the `Downloads` shell folder.

See also the Microsoft documentations for [Known Folders](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/shell/known-folders) and [KNOWNFOLDERID](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/shell/knownfolderid) and the other documentation pages referenced on these pages as well as the documentation about [Application Registration](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/shell/app-registration).

Here is a batch file which gets the user's desktop directory from Windows registry as much safe as possible.

```
@echo off
setlocal EnableExtensions DisableDelayedExpansion

set "DesktopFolder="
for /F "skip=1 tokens=1,2*" %%I in ('%SystemRoot%\System32\reg.exe QUERY "HKCU\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Explorer\User Shell Folders" /v Desktop 2^>nul') do if /I "%%I" == "Desktop" if not "%%~K" == "" if "%%J" == "REG_SZ" (set "DesktopFolder=%%~K") else if "%%J" == "REG_EXPAND_SZ" call set "DesktopFolder=%%~K"
if not defined DesktopFolder for /F "skip=1 tokens=1,2*" %%I in ('%SystemRoot%\System32\reg.exe QUERY "HKCU\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Explorer\Shell Folders" /v Desktop 2^>nul') do if /I "%%I" == "Desktop" if not "%%~K" == "" if "%%J" == "REG_SZ" (set "DesktopFolder=%%~K") else if "%%J" == "REG_EXPAND_SZ" call set "DesktopFolder=%%~K"
if not defined DesktopFolder set "DesktopFolder=\"
if "%DesktopFolder:~-1%" == "\" set "DesktopFolder=%DesktopFolder:~0,-1%"
if not defined DesktopFolder set "DesktopFolder=%UserProfile%\Desktop"

echo User's desktop folder is: %DesktopFolder%

endlocal
```

This batch file works even on Windows XP on which `reg.exe` outputs the results of the query different to `reg.exe` of Windows Vista and newer Windows versions.

See Microsoft article about [Using command redirection operators](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/windows/it-pro/windows-xp/bb490982(v=technet.10)) for an explanation of `2>nul` which redirects the error message output by command **MD** on directory already existing to handle **STDERR** to the device **NUL** to suppress this error message.

However, the user's desktop directory should contain only shortcut files (`*.lnk` files) and the files and directories created by the user on the desktop. No program should create ever other files than shortcut files in the user's desktop directory. Microsoft defined several other shell folders for applications like `APPDATA` (application data) or `LOCALAPPDATA` (local application data) for applications.

---

Some additional facts about handling of string value `Desktop` under the keys `User Shell Folders` and `Shell Folders` by Windows as observed with Windows XP SP3 x86 with always restarting Windows after making a change in registry hive of current user:

1. A change of the path string of the string value `Desktop` under the key `User Shell Folders` for example from `%USERPROFILE%\Desktop` to `%USERPROFILE%\MyDesktop` and of course creation of the directory `%USERPROFILE%\MyDesktop` changes the Windows desktop directory to custom `%USERPROFILE%\MyDesktop` on next log on and the string value of `Desktop` under key `Shell Folders` is adapted by Windows on next restart. It was not tested by me if `Desktop` under the key `Shell Folders` is adapted also on just doing a log off and log on. It is definitely better to change both `Desktop` string values at the same time to change the desktop directory permanently to a directory different from default `%USERPROFILE%\Desktop`.
2. A removed or renamed string value `Desktop` under the key `User Shell Folders` is never recreated by Windows. So it is possible that this string value does not exist if `Desktop` under the key `User Shell Folders` was by mistake once deleted or renamed or the registry file is partly damaged with the result that this string value does not exist. A user would not notice that issue as the further tests below showed.
3. The string value `Desktop` of type `REG_SZ` under key `Shell Folders` is always set to expanded path of `%USERPROFILE%\Desktop` if string value `Desktop` of type `REG_EXPAND_SZ` under key `User Shell Folders` does not exist at all. Windows creates also the directory `%USERPROFILE%\Desktop` automatically if not existing in this error handling case
4. If the string value `Desktop` of type `REG_SZ` under key `Shell Folders` **and** the string value `Desktop` of type `REG_EXPAND_SZ` under key `User Shell Folders` are **both** deleted or renamed by a user or program, Windows creates on next start the string value `Desktop` of type `REG_SZ` under key `Shell Folders` with expanded path of `%USERPROFILE%\Desktop` and creates also the directory if not existing. The string value `Desktop` of type `REG_EXPAND_SZ` under key `USer Shell Folders` is **not** recreated by Windows.
5. If the string value `Desktop` of type `REG_SZ` under key `Shell Folders` exists with a different expanded path than `%USERPROFILE%\Desktop` like expanded path of `%USERPROFILE%\MyDesktop` and the string value `Desktop` of type `REG_EXPAND_SZ` under the key `User Shell Folders` does not exit at all, Windows ignores the customized path of `Desktop` of type `REG_SZ` under the key `Shell Folders` and sets the value to expanded path of `%USERPROFILE%\Desktop` and creates additionally the directory `%USERPROFILE%\Desktop` if not already existing. So it is not possible to use a customized desktop directory without having the customized desktop directory defined also with string value `Desktop` of type `REG_EXPAND_SZ` under the key `User Shell Folders`.

I did not make tests with newer versions on Windows regarding to handling of `Desktop` under the keys `Shell Folders` and `User Shell Folders` if one or both string values do not exist and/or have same or different directory paths and/or have a directory path different to default.

Answer (score 0):

I reccomend to use this script:

```
@echo off
if exist "%userprofile%\OneDrive\Desktop" (chdir %userprofile%\OneDrive\Desktop) else (chdir %userprofile%\Desktop)
```

If someone installed OneDrive on windows setup, their desktop will probably be  located under OneDrive folder. Else it will be User\Desktop.

Comment: I wouldn't recommend doing that. The existence of a folder doesn't mean their desktop is located there. And it could be somewhere else entirely. The default location may not even exist. So the best solution is to just use the registry.

Comment: `for /f "tokens=2*" %%a in ('reg query "HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Explorer\User Shell Folders" /v Desktop') do set DESKTOP=%%b`

Answer (score -1):

Environ("USERPROFILE") & "\Desktop"