# Change youtube-dl download output (Windows)

Tags: batch-file, ffmpeg, youtube-dl, ffprobe

I hope you can help me.

I am using youtube-dl on windows (youtube-dl.exe)
Downloading the video works great and also just the audio. But what i want is for it to save the audio file in a different place eg. **C:\Users*******\Desktop**

I made a batch file with this code:

```
:audio
cls
echo.
echo.
echo Your audio vill be downloaded and saved as a .mp3 format
echo.
echo.
set /p audio=Enter Video URL here:
cls
youtube-dl.exe --extract-audio --audio-format mp3 --output C:\Users\*******\Desktop\(ext)s.%(ext)s %audio%
pause
cls
echo.
echo.
echo.
echo.
echo Your audio has now been downloaded.
ping localhost -n 3 >nul
exit
```

and then it gives me this

```
Usage: youtube-dl.exe [OPTIONS] URL [URL...]

youtube-dl.exe: error: You must provide at least one URL.
Type youtube-dl --help to see a list of all options.
Press any key to continue . . .
```

It works fine if i use this but it saves it in the same folder.

```
:audio
cls
echo.
echo.
echo Your audio vill be downloaded and saved as a .mp3 format
echo.
echo.
set /p audio=Enter Video URL here:
cls
youtube-dl.exe --extract-audio --audio-format mp3 %audio%
pause
cls
echo.
echo.
echo.
echo.
echo Your audio has now been downloaded.
ping localhost -n 3 >nul
exit
```

Also please keep in mind that it also uses **ffprobe.exe** and **ffmpeg.exe** (They are both in the same folder as youtube-dl.exe

Comment: I don't suppose you have spaces in your user name?

Comment: It would be best to make the save to path a var and allow the user to input it into the batch

Answer (score 3):

Open a command prompt window and run there `cmd /?`. This command outputs the help for the Windows command processor. On last help page in last paragraph there is written which characters in a directory or file name or arguments of executables and scripts require the usage of double quotes: space and  `` &()[]{}^=;!'+,`~ ``

The character `%` has a special meaning in batch files as it marks the beginning and end of an immediately expanded environment variable reference or a batch file argument reference or a loop variable reference. The percent sign must be escaped with one more `%` to specify a literally interpreted `%` character.

In command prompt window run `set` and there are displayed the standard environment variables for the user account on the machine. One of those standard environment variables is **USERPROFILE** which holds the path to the current user's profile folder containing by default, for example, the subfolder `Desktop`.

Now let us look on the following line from your batch file:

```
youtube-dl.exe --extract-audio --audio-format mp3 --output C:\Users\*******\Desktop\(ext)s.%(ext)s %audio%
```

It would be good to use here a reference to the environment variable **USERPROFILE** for the `Desktop` directory. The user account name could contain a space character and therefore it is advisable to enclose the path in double quotes. Next there are parentheses and a single percent sign which definitely require double quotes and escaping the percent sign.

The URL stored in environment variable `audio` can't contain a space character as in URLs a space character must be encoded with %20. But this single percent sign causes again troubles on interpreting the line by Windows command processor. The solution is using delayed expansion.

Let us look on this batch code:

```
@echo off
setlocal EnableExtensions EnableDelayedExpansion
set "ToolPath=%~dp0"
cd /D "%USERPROFILE%\Desktop"
rem The directory may not exist. It would be a good idea to check that.
:audio
cls
echo/
echo/
echo Your audio will be downloaded and saved as a .mp3 format
echo/
echo/
set "audio="
:PromptUser
set /P "audio=Enter audio URL here: "
if not defined audio goto PromptUser
set "audio=!audio:"=!"
if not defined audio goto PromptUser
"%ToolPath%youtube-dl.exe" --extract-audio --audio-format mp3 --output "%USERPROFILE%\Desktop\(ext)s.%%(ext)s" "!audio!"
pause
cls
echo/
echo/
echo/
echo/
echo Your audio has now been downloaded.
%SystemRoot%\System32\ping.exe 127.0.0.1 -n 4 >nul
endlocal
```

The batch file first creates a local copy of all environment variables, enables command extensions and delayed variable expansion, and pushes also current working directory path on stack.

Next the path of the directory containing the batch file and the other executables used by this batch file is assigned to variable `ToolPath`. Run in command prompt window `call /?` for details on `%~dp0` (drive and path of argument 0 – the batch file – always ending with a backslash).

Then the current directory is changed to the `Desktop` directory of the currently used user account independent from which drive the batch file was started. Run in command prompt window `cd /?` for details about this command and its options.

The line with `youtube-dl.exe` is changed as now the executable is called with full path (as current working directory is now the user's `Desktop` directory). Also the output directory is enclosed now in double quotes, uses also environment variable **USERPROFILE**, has escaped the single percent sign with one more `%` and the URL is referenced now in double quotes using delayed expansion (exclamation marks instead of percent signs). Run in a command prompt window `set /?` for help and details about delayed expansion.

For a timeout of 3 seconds the value used on command **PING** must be 4 as the first ping is always immediately successful.

The command **ENDLOCAL** results in discarding the local copy of the table with the environment variables (`ToolPath` is not defined anymore after this line and all changes on other variables are lost), restores previous values for delayed expansion (most likely turning it off as not enabled by default) and command extensions (most likely being still enabled as by default) and also restoring previous working directory (most likely the path of the batch file if started with a double click).

See also:

- [How does the Windows Command Interpreter (CMD.EXE) parse scripts?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4094699/)
- DosTips forum topic: [ECHO. FAILS to give text or blank line - Instead use ECHO/](https://www.dostips.com/forum/viewtopic.php?f=3&t=774)
- [How to stop Windows command interpreter from quitting batch file execution on an incorrect user input?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49834019/3074564)
- [Path of user desktop in batch files](https://stackoverflow.com/a/69602421/3074564)