# Creating files at PSModulePath in batch

Tags: powershell, batch-file, cmd, module

I am currently trying to write a batch program that installs a module named `SetConsolePath.psm1` at the correct location. I am a beginner with Batch and I have absolutely no powershell experience.

Through the internet, I have learned how to display `PSModulePath` with `powershell -command "echo $env:PSModulePath`.

How can I, via .bat file, move `SetConsolePath.psm1` from the desktop to the location displayed by `powershell -command "echo $env:PSModulePath`?

Thank you in advance, and I apologize for my lack of experience.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Before I answer, I must out that you do not want to copy PowerShell module files directly to the path pointed by `PsModulePath`.  You really want to create a folder inside `PSModulePath` and copy the files there instead.

The prefix `env` in a Powershell variable indicates an *environment variable*. `$env:PSModulePath` is actually referring to the `PSMODULEPATH` environment variable.  On the command line, and in batch files, environment variables can be displayed by placing the name between percent symbols.  (In fact, you could have displayed this value by typing `echo %PSMODULEPATH%` instead.)

To reference the desktop folder, have a look at [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18630102/1001100), which shows you how to use another environment variable, `USERPROFILE`.

Therefore, to copy the file from the desktop directory to the path specified in `PSModulePath`, you would do this:

```
COPY "%USERPROFILE%\Desktop\SetConsolePath.psm1" "%PSMODULEPATH%"
```

And, as I warned earlier, you really should copy the file to a folder underneath `PsModulePath`.  So what you really want is:

```
IF NOT EXIST "%PSMODULEPATH%\MyNewFolder" MKDIR "%PSMODULEPATH%\MyNewFolder"
COPY "%USERPROFILE%\Desktop\SetConsolePath.psm1" "%PSMODULEPATH%\MyNewFolder"
```