# How to create a directory in the user's desktop directory?

Tags: batch-file

So I am making a batch file that I will put in the startup folder. I need to make a directory in the desktop directory of current user. I only know how to make a new directory in the current directory.

The only way I know how to make a directory is with the command `mkdir`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The **default** for the Windows desktop directory is defined with `%USERPROFILE%\Desktop`. `USERPROFILE` is one of the predefined [Windows environment variables](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Environment_variable#Windows).

So it would be possible to use just:

```
md "%UserProfile%\Desktop\NewDirectory" 2>nul
```

That would create a directory with name `NewDirectory` on user's desktop as long as the user has not changed the default for the desktop directory. The command `md` can be use with a full qualified directory path or a relative directory path. The help output on running in a [command prompt](https://www.howtogeek.com/235101/10-ways-to-open-the-command-prompt-in-windows-10/) `md /?` explains that `md` creates the entire directory tree to a directory not existing if command extensions are enabled as by default. See also the Microsoft documentation for [naming files, paths, and namespaces](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/fileio/naming-a-file).

But it would be better to get the desktop directory path from Windows registry instead of using simply the default. There are two registry keys containing a string value with name `Desktop` with the path to user's desktop directory:

- `HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Explorer\User Shell Folders`
  This registry key contains several string values usually of type `REG_EXPAND_SZ` which define the paths to the various shell folders defined for the current user account. The shell folders contain usually an environment variable reference like `%USERPROFILE%` which is the reason for the type `REG_EXPAND_SZ` which means the string value must be additionally expanded to get absolute path to the shell folder. The batch file below expands the environment variable reference by using the command **CALL** to force one more command line parsing by Windows command processor.
  For example, the command `set "DesktopFolder=%%~K"` becomes first on execution of `for` the command `set "DesktopFolder=%USERPROFILE%\Desktop"`. This command is parsed a second time by `cmd.exe` to something like `set "DesktopFolder=C:\Users\UserName\Desktop"` because of the command `call` before really executing the command `set` to define the environment variable `DesktopFolder` with the real absolute folder name read from the Windows registry.
- `HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Explorer\Shell Folders`
  This registry key contains nearly the same string values as the registry key above, but the string values are usually of type `REG_SZ`. This registry key is for downwards compatibility for applications not supporting the other registry key with the string values with environment variable references.

It is possible that a shell folder is defined only in one of the two registry keys. For example on Windows XP the string values `Administrative Tools`, `CD Burning`, `Fonts` and `Recent` exist only under registry key `Shell Folders` and do not exist under key `User Shell Folders`.

Information added by [Compo](https://stackoverflow.com/users/6738015/compo):

1. Windows itself uses by default the string values defined under key `User Shell Folders` and uses a string value defined under key `Shell Folders` only if not existing under key `User Shell Folders`.
2. Windows does not propagate a modification on a string value under key `User Shell Folders` to the string value with same name under key `Shell Folders` if a user or a program modifies directly in registry a string value under key `User Shell Folders` without making appropriate change to key with same name under key `Shell Folders`.
   So in case of `Desktop` in `User Shell Folders` contains a different directory path than `Desktop` in `Shell Folders`, Windows uses the path defined with `Desktop` in `User Shell Folders`.

A user has the freedom to change any folder to whatever the user wants. But the user must take care to change a string value in both registry keys on existing twice. Some of the shell folders can be easily modified via an option on graphical user interface of Windows or a Windows application like the `Downloads` shell folder.

See also the Microsoft documentations for [Known Folders](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/shell/known-folders) and [KNOWNFOLDERID](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/shell/knownfolderid) and the other documentation pages referenced on these pages as well as the documentation about [Application Registration](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/shell/app-registration).

Here is a batch file which gets the user's desktop directory from Windows registry as much safe as possible.

```
@echo off
setlocal EnableExtensions DisableDelayedExpansion

set "DesktopFolder="
for /F "skip=2 tokens=1,2*" %%I in ('%SystemRoot%\System32\reg.exe QUERY "HKCU\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Explorer\User Shell Folders" /v Desktop 2^>nul') do if /I "%%I" == "Desktop" if not "%%~K" == "" if "%%J" == "REG_SZ" (set "DesktopFolder=%%~K") else if "%%J" == "REG_EXPAND_SZ" call set "DesktopFolder=%%~K"
if not defined DesktopFolder for /F "skip=2 tokens=1,2*" %%I in ('%SystemRoot%\System32\reg.exe QUERY "HKCU\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Explorer\Shell Folders" /v Desktop 2^>nul') do if /I "%%I" == "Desktop" if not "%%~K" == "" if "%%J" == "REG_SZ" (set "DesktopFolder=%%~K") else if "%%J" == "REG_EXPAND_SZ" call set "DesktopFolder=%%~K"
if not defined DesktopFolder set "DesktopFolder=\"
if "%DesktopFolder:~-1%" == "\" set "DesktopFolder=%DesktopFolder:~0,-1%"
if not defined DesktopFolder set "DesktopFolder=%UserProfile%\Desktop"

md "%DesktopFolder%\NewDirectory" 2>nul

endlocal
```

This batch file works even on Windows XP on which `reg.exe` outputs the results of the query different to `reg.exe` of Windows Vista and newer Windows versions.

See Microsoft article about [Using command redirection operators](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/windows/it-pro/windows-xp/bb490982(v=technet.10)) for an explanation of `2>nul` which redirects the error message output by command **MD** on directory already existing to handle **STDERR** to the device **NUL** to suppress this error message.

However, the user's desktop directory should contain only shortcut files (`*.lnk` files) and the files and directories created by the user on the desktop. No program should create ever other files than shortcut files in the user's desktop directory. Microsoft defined several other shell folders for applications like `APPDATA` (application data) or `LOCALAPPDATA` (local application data) for applications.

---

Some additional facts about handling of string value `Desktop` under the keys `User Shell Folders` and `Shell Folders` by Windows as observed with Windows XP SP3 x86 with always restarting Windows after making a change in registry hive of current user:

1. A change of the path string of the string value `Desktop` under the key `User Shell Folders` for example from `%USERPROFILE%\Desktop` to `%USERPROFILE%\MyDesktop` and of course creation of the directory `%USERPROFILE%\MyDesktop` changes the Windows desktop directory to custom `%USERPROFILE%\MyDesktop` on next log on and the string value of `Desktop` under key `Shell Folders` is adapted by Windows on next restart. It was not tested by me if `Desktop` under the key `Shell Folders` is adapted also on just doing a log off and log on. It is definitely better to change both `Desktop` string values at the same time to change the desktop directory permanently to a directory different from default `%USERPROFILE%\Desktop`.
2. A removed or renamed string value `Desktop` under the key `User Shell Folders` is never recreated by Windows. So it is possible that this string value does not exist if `Desktop` under the key `User Shell Folders` was by mistake once deleted or renamed or the registry file is partly damaged with the result that this string value does not exist. A user would not notice that issue as the further tests below showed.
3. The string value `Desktop` of type `REG_SZ` under key `Shell Folders` is always set to expanded path of `%USERPROFILE%\Desktop` if string value `Desktop` of type `REG_EXPAND_SZ` under key `User Shell Folders` does not exist at all. Windows creates also the directory `%USERPROFILE%\Desktop` automatically if not existing in this error handling case
4. If the string value `Desktop` of type `REG_SZ` under key `Shell Folders` **and** the string value `Desktop` of type `REG_EXPAND_SZ` under key `User Shell Folders` are **both** deleted or renamed by a user or program, Windows creates on next start the string value `Desktop` of type `REG_SZ` under key `Shell Folders` with expanded path of `%USERPROFILE%\Desktop` and creates also the directory if not existing. The string value `Desktop` of type `REG_EXPAND_SZ` under key `USer Shell Folders` is **not** recreated by Windows.
5. If the string value `Desktop` of type `REG_SZ` under key `Shell Folders` exists with a different expanded path than `%USERPROFILE%\Desktop` like expanded path of `%USERPROFILE%\MyDesktop` and the string value `Desktop` of type `REG_EXPAND_SZ` under the key `User Shell Folders` does not exit at all, Windows ignores the customized path of `Desktop` of type `REG_SZ` under the key `Shell Folders` and sets the value to expanded path of `%USERPROFILE%\Desktop` and creates additionally the directory `%USERPROFILE%\Desktop` if not already existing. So it is not possible to use a customized desktop directory without having the customized desktop directory defined also with string value `Desktop` of type `REG_EXPAND_SZ` under the key `User Shell Folders`.

I did not make tests with newer versions on Windows regarding to handling of `Desktop` under the keys `Shell Folders` and `User Shell Folders` if one or both string values do not exist and/or have same or different directory paths and/or have a directory path different to default.

Comment: Just to mention that the data held under value of the `User Shell Folders` key of `HKEY_CURRENT_USER` takes precedence over `Shell Folders` and over the `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE` key values. A change to the USF key doesn't automatically propagate to the SF key, which could therefore hold a different value. This of course means that the above extended version of my existing answer, should really be modified to retrieve the value of the USF key first and if that isn't defined, try the SF key.

Comment: @Compo You are absolutely right. I verified your information on Windows 7. I added the information to my answer and updated the code of the batch file. Thank you.

Comment: No problem, just take account that if the value from the USF key, is not defined, it means that the user has at some point removed it, and has therefore done something they shouldn't have. This therefore means that the value under the SF key cannot be expected to hold the correct value either. That is the reason my code only makes its assessment based upon any data held under the USF key.

Comment: @Compo I observed on Windows XP a different behavior as written in your comment above. If `Desktop` under the key `User Shell Folders` does not exist, it will not be recreated by Windows, but in this case Windows always sets `Desktop` under the key `Shell Folders` to expanded path of default `%USERPROFILE%\Desktop` and makes sure that this directory exists. See the facts of my observations added to the answer. So if `Desktop` under the key `User Shell Folders` does not exist, `Desktop` under the key `Shell Folders` exists always (after a Windows restart) with default desktop path.

Answer (score 0):

I would offer a method which retrieves the path from the registry:

```bat
@For /F "EOL=HTokens=2*" %%A In ('^""%__AppDir__%Reg.exe" Query^
 "HKCU\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Explorer\User Shell Folders"^
 /V Desktop^" 2^>NUL')Do @Call MD "%%B\New Directory" 2>NUL
```

The above is designed to create a directory named `New Directory`, *(change as required)*, on the current users desktop.

Comment: Is `"%userprofile%\desktop"` unreliable other than language?