# CMD: "echo." new line character doesn't work (merge .txt files with line break)

Tags: batch-file, cmd

I have a bunch of .txt files:

- 1.txt containing string "1"
- 2.txt containing string "2"
- 3.txt containing string "3"

I need to **combine** them to get "result.txt" containing **this:**

```
1
2
3
```

I used `echo.` as *a new line character* in a **batch**:

```
for /r %%i in (*.txt) do (
type %%i>> result.txt
echo.>> result.txt
)
```

But in "result.txt" I'm getting this:

```
1
2.
3.
```

So, `echo.` actually works perfectly well **for the first** (1.txt) file, but it also puts a `.` before new lines for **the rest** of the files.

Can someone please fix batch code for me?

P.S.: the problem occurred because .txt files were located in different subfolders - that's why I used `for /r` initially (it doesn't always work, see details below!).

Comment: I can't reproduce, the result I get using Windows 10 CMD is exactly 9 bytes; in hex: `31 0D 0A 32 0D 0A 33 0D 0A`

Comment: Can't reproduce that either, but use `echo/` rather than `echo.` (the latter initiates a file system access, and when a file `echo.` (no extension) is found, it fails). How are the input files encoded? ASCII/ANSI or Unicode?

Comment: @aschipfl I just create blank .txt from Windows 8.1 context menu and put one string characters inside; I noticed though that dots `.` only appear if .txt's are **located in subfolders!** that's why I initially used `for /r`; have you got any clue?

Comment: @aschipfl I also tried `echo/`, but didn't help.

Comment: Use `echo(>>result.txt` instead of `echo.>> result.txt`. For the reason read completely the DosTips forum topic: [ECHO. FAILS to give text or blank line - Instead use ECHO/](https://www.dostips.com/forum/viewtopic.php?f=3&t=774)

Comment: @Mofi **THANK YOU!!!** <3

Comment: PS: On FAT32 and exFAT drives the `for /R` loop does not produce the expected result as writing `result.txt` into the current directory while iterating over the list of `*.txt` files in current directory and its subdirectories directly from the file system results in processing the `*.txt` files in current directory more than once. The better __FOR__ loop is `for /F "delims=" %%i in ('dir *.txt /A-D /B /ON /S 2^>nul') do (` which works on all drives independent on file system as first the list of text files is loaded into memory and then iterating over the file names list in memory.

Comment: PPS: The `dir` option `/ON` results in a different order of the file names than NTFS uses to store the file names in the file allocation table. So it is advisable that the file names are not `1.txt`, `2.txt`, ..., `9.txt`, `10.txt`, etc. but `01.txt`, `02.txt`, ..., `09.txt`, `10.txt`, etc.

Comment: @Mofi could you please rewrite `for /F "delims=" %%i in ('dir *.txt /A-D /B /ON /S 2^>nul') do (` for, say "C:\Users\123\Desktop\Folder" - ??

Comment: @VictorNovak `for /F "delims=" %%i in ('dir "%UserProfile%\Desktop\Folder\*.txt" /A-D /B /ON /S 2^>nul') do (` for a recursive processing with file names with full path assigned to loop variable `i` or  `for /F "eol=| delims=" %%i in ('dir "%UserProfile%\Desktop\Folder\*.txt" /A-D /B /ON 2^>nul') do (` for just file name with extension, but without file path assigned to loop variable `i`. The first solution requires to use `type "%%i">>result.txt` and the second solution `type "%UserProfile%\Desktop\Folder\%%i">>result.txt`.

Comment: @Mofi thank you again so much! I didn't expect this task to consume all my day :D I'm currently reading this for details https://ss64.com/nt/dir.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks **@Mofi**, see his comments below the starting post!

This is a solution for а `Folder` on (any) user's `Desktop`:

```
for /f "delims=" %%i in ('dir "%UserProfile%\Desktop\Folder\*.txt" /a-d /b /on /s 2^>nul') do (
echo %%~fi>> result.txt
type "%%i">> result.txt
echo(>> result.txt
)
```

- `echo %%~fi>> result.txt` adds full path to any *.txt file found in
  that folder (**and** subfolders);
- `type "%%i">> result.txt` merges found *.txt files
  contents;
- `echo(>> result.txt` is the new line character requested!

This code tested on NTFS and is promised to work on FAT\FAT32 etc. - unlike `for /R` (see @Mofi comments below the starting post!).

P.S.: you can launch this batch code from any location; also, use `echo {anytext}>> result.txt` after `echo(>> result.txt` to easily navigate between breaks in "result.txt" :)

P.P.S.: also, if you want to **get rid of blank line** in the EOF "result.txt" - use this:

```
set /a counter1=0
set /a counter2=0

::cycle 1
for /f "delims=" %%i in ('dir "%UserProfile%\Desktop\Folder\*.txt" /a-d /b /on /s 2^>nul') do (
set /a counter1+=1
)

::cycle 2
setlocal enableextensions enabledelayedexpansion
for /f "delims=" %%i in ('dir "%UserProfile%\Desktop\Folder\*.txt" /a-d /b /on /s 2^>nul') do (
echo %%~fi>> result.txt
type "%%i">> result.txt
set /a counter2+=1
if not !counter2!==%counter1% (echo(>> result.txt)
)
endlocal
```

Inspired by: https://stackoverflow.com/a/7522822/6859021

- both cycles has the same `for /f` conditions;
- `::cycle 1` counts number of files that are about to undergo the procedure;
- `::cycle 2` is identical to original solution, except for "Inspired
  by" details;
- `::*` lines are comments: they don't affect code
  execution;
- `if not !counter2!==%counter1% (echo(>> result.txt)` merely puts `echo(` for all lines, except for the last one! **:D**

Notice however that counters will work properly only if "result.txt" will NOT be located inside `Folder` of interest, or it's subfolders.

Comment: `%UserProfile%` doesn't work if user's `Desktop` is located on different HDD (when system drive is SSD, for example): `%HOMEPATH%\Desktop` does the charm for both!

Comment: Neither `%UserProfile%\Desktop` nor `%HOMEPATH%\Desktop` are always correct to reference the directory being the user's desktop. See [How to create a directory in the user's desktop directory?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/58516212/3074564) It explains in full details how to query the user's desktop directory from Windows registry working even on user has changed the user's desktop directory for example to a directory being included for OneDrive synchronization.

Comment: Batch syntax is so confusing, omg ><
Thanks again @Mofi!

Answer (score 0):

First: I could not reproduce the problem where additional dots are added to the file.

However I found a different issue, that might have to do something with it. When you are iterating over all text-files, you get the result.txt at one point as well. (And other files you might add or change during runtime.)

So I created this basic script, which does exactly what you described as your desired behavior:

```
@echo off
:: clear 
rd testdir /s /q 2>nul

:: create files
md testdir
cd testdir
for /l %%i in (1 1 3) do (
  <nul set /p "=%%i">"%%i.txt"
)

:: combine the files
for /r %%f in (*.txt) do (
  if not "%%~nf"=="result" (
    type "%%f">>result.txt
    echo.>>result.txt
  )
)

:: show result
echo result.txt
type result.txt
pause
```