# Variable value extracted from registry is not expanded

Tags: windows, batch-file

I'm trying to use the value of an environment variable I capture from a registry key in a batch script, but for whatever reason unknown to me, the variable does not get expanded.

However, I can get it resolved if I do not capture it from the registry.

This is the script:

```
ECHO ON
SETLOCAL ENABLEDELAYEDEXPANSION
CLS

FOR /F "tokens=2*" %%a IN ('REG QUERY "HKCU\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Explorer\User Shell Folders" /v "Desktop" 2^>^&1^|find "REG_"') DO @SET SHORTCUTDESTINATION=%%b
ECHO %SHORTCUTDESTINATION%
PAUSE

SET VALUEFROMREGISTRY=%SHORTCUTDESTINATION%

ECHO %VALUEFROMREGISTRY%
PAUSE
ECHO %USERPROFILE%
PAUSE
```

This is the outcome - Results within the red rectangle are not resolved; in green, they are.

[image: batch]

What am I missing?

Comment: The value you are extracting is supposed to be of value type `REG_EXPAND_SZ`. As such its value should contain a variable for expanding. In order to do that you would need to expand that value by `Echo`ing the value within another cmd.exe instance, through another `For /F` command. For example: ```@For /F "EOL=H Tokens=2,*" %%G In ('%SystemRoot%\System32\reg.exe Query "HKCU\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Explorer\User Shell Folders" /V Desktop 2^>NUL ^| %SystemRoot%\System32\find.exe /I "REG_"') Do @For /F "Delims=" %%I In ('Echo "%%~H"') Do @Set "SHORTCUTDESTINATION=%%~I"```.

Comment: I suggest to take a look at [How to create a directory in the user's desktop directory?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/58516212/3074564)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use **call echo** and **call set** to force cmd to expand the %userprofile% system variable.

```
ECHO ON
SETLOCAL ENABLEDELAYEDEXPANSION
CLS

FOR /F "tokens=2*" %%a IN ('REG QUERY "HKCU\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Explorer\User Shell Folders" /v "Desktop" 2^>^&1^|find "REG_"') DO @SET SHORTCUTDESTINATION=%%b
ECHO %SHORTCUTDESTINATION%
call echo %SHORTCUTDESTINATION%
PAUSE

SET VALUEFROMREGISTRY=%SHORTCUTDESTINATION%
call SET VALUEFROMREGISTRYCALL=%SHORTCUTDESTINATION%

ECHO %VALUEFROMREGISTRY%
ECHO %VALUEFROMREGISTRYCALL%
PAUSE
ECHO %USERPROFILE%
PAUSE
```

Comment: To make it shorter, couldn't you just use `FOR /F "tokens=2*" %%a IN ('REG QUERY "HKCU\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Explorer\User Shell Folders" /v "Desktop" 2^>^&1^|find "REG_"') DO @call set "SHORTCUTDESTINATION=%%b"` here?

Comment: @Qwerty Yes in this case that would be sufficient. But if you would want to change such a registry key than you should do that only with the unexpanded key (the one with %userprofile% in its value).

Comment: The CALL SET did the trick @OJBakker - Thank you!