# Using Windows 10 batch file for reading desktop location from Registry, value not returning correctly

Tags: windows, batch-file, registry

I am trying to write a script that among other things tries to create a shortcut up on a user's desktop.  The problem I discovered was that some users don't use the standard location for their desktop location.

I implemented the following code to read the value from the Registry:

```
for /f "usebackq tokens=3*" %%D IN (`reg query "HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Explorer\User Shell Folders" /v Desktop`) do set DESKTOP=%%D

CALL SET REGISTRYDESKTOP=%DESKTOP%

echo Desktop is located in "%REGISTRYDESKTOP%"
```

When I looked at the Registry, I see the following:
[image]

When the code runs, I get the following response:
[image]

I imagine I am missing something simple, what am I doing wrong here?

Regards,

Steve

Comment: Try ```@For /F "EOL=H Tokens=2,*" %%G In ('%SystemRoot%\System32\reg.exe Query "HKCU\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Explorer\User Shell Folders" /V Desktop 2^>NUL') Do @Set "DESKTOP=%%~H"``` instead

Comment: Using `call set` will also work as in `for /f "tokens=2*" %%a in ('%__APPDIR__%reg.exe query "HKCU\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Explorer\User Shell Folders" /v "Desktop" 2^>^&1') do call set "deskFold=%%b`.

Comment: You don't have to re-invent this, look [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/58516212/3074564).

Comment: Okay, I keep digging on this, and what I am finding is that the new location for the profile is "C:\Users\<userid>\OneDrive - <company Name>\Desktop"  I think the problem is that I have spaces in the path name.  what my code is returning is "C:\Users\<userid>\OneDrive"   I have tried quoting the whole thing, but quotes already there are interfering with eachother.  Syntax help anyone?

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for all your help.

The final answer did turn out to be rather simple.  First I needed to update the  tokens clause of where I retrieved the string from the registry:

```
for /f "usebackq tokens=*" %%D IN (`reg query 
    "HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Explorer\User Shell Folders"
    /v Desktop`) do set DESKTOP=%%D
```

and second I needed to update the call set line:

`CALL SET "REGISTRYDESKTOP=%DESKTOP:*REG_EXPAND_SZ    =%"`

Hope this helps anyone else facing this issue.